# Vowel/consonant counter in Golang

Tags: beginner, go

To learn Go I decided to write a vowel/consonant counter. I really need tips/ideas on how I can improve my code.

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
)

func isVowel(x string) bool {
    vowels := [5]string{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u",}
    vowelLookupTable := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, v := range vowels {
        vowelLookupTable[v] = true
    }

    return vowelLookupTable[x]
}

func isConsonant(x string) bool {
    consonants := [21]string{"b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    consonantLookupTable := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, v := range consonants {
        consonantLookupTable[v] = true
    }

    return consonantLookupTable[x]

}

func formatNumbers(vowelCount int, consonantCount int) {
    fmt.Print("Consonants: ")

    for i := 0; i < consonantCount; i++ {
        fmt.Print("=")
    }

    fmt.Printf(" %d\n", consonantCount)

    fmt.Print("Vowels:     ")

    for i := 0; i < vowelCount; i++ {
        fmt.Print("=")
    }

    fmt.Printf(" %d\n", vowelCount)
}

func countVowels(input string) int {
    vowelCount := 0

    for _, x:= range input {
        var s string
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%c", x)
        if isVowel(s) {
            vowelCount += 1
        }
    }

    return vowelCount
}

func countConsonants(input string) int {
    consonantCount := 0

    for _, x:= range input {
        var s string
        s = fmt.Sprintf("%c", x)
        if isConsonant(s) {
            consonantCount += 1
        }
    }

    return consonantCount
}

func takeInput() string {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    return text
}

func main() {
    input := takeInput()

    vowelCount := countVowels(input)
    consonantCount := countConsonants(input)

    formatNumbers(vowelCount, consonantCount)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for provoking me to have a deeper a look into the exciting Go language :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [Handle errors.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#handle-errors) In Go, `foo, _ := something()` is a big code smell.
- Iterating on a string gives you a `rune`; don't convert it to a one-char string just to compare it to another one-char string. Compare it to another `rune` instead (`'a'` instead of `"a"`).
- Your functions `isVowel` and `isConsonant` are re-building the vowel/consonant map from scratch *every time they're called*! This is very inefficient: initialize both maps as package variables, and inline these two functions completely. You have two options to do so, I like the second one better because it's slightly more readable.

  Option 1:

  ```
  var (
      vowels = map[rune]bool{
          'a': true,
          'e': true,
          'i': true,
          'o': true,
          'u': true,
      }
      consonants = map[rune]bool{
          // …
      }
  )
  ```

  Option 2:

  ```
  var (
      vowels = toSet('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
      consonants = toSet(/* … */)
  )
  func toSet(chars ...rune) map[rune]bool {
      m := make(map[rune]bool, len(chars))
      for _, c := range chars {
          m[c] = true
      }
      return m
  }
  ```

  You then check if a rune `r` is a vowel by just calling `vowels[r]`.
- Your `s = fmt.Sprintf("%c", x)` statement looks a lot like printf debugging. Were you intending to keep it in your code?
- `countVowels` and `countConsonants` can be inlined as well, and called on each char in the same loop like in Curtis' answer.
- Replace `foo += 1` by `foo++`.
- I'd say you have needless blank lines in your code (I think each of your functions is simple enough not to have any), but that's a minor style thing.
- Your code doesn't support non-ASCII encodings (and it probably should, UTF-8 is everywhere nowadays). It doesn't support uppercase letters, either =)

Answer (score 2):

You should use a simple `switch` statement, like this:

```
func isVowel(r rune) bool {
    switch r {
    case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u':
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

This is much more efficient than creating a map each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the intended solution obviously has to **process user input**, I focused on the `rune`s that are neither vowels nor consonants. I also found it **confusing to iterate more than once**, and I came to this solution. I'm an absolute Go beginner, so I'm currently not able to separate map building and analysis. But I'm thankful to this interesting experience practising Go's `map`s, loops, error handling strategy (double assign), and formatting capabilities:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type RuneTypeCounts struct {
  vowels, consonants, other int
}

func analyseText(text string) RuneTypeCounts {
  var result RuneTypeCounts
  m := make(map[rune]*int)
  for _, r := range "aeiou" {
    m[r] = &result.vowels
  }
  for _, r := range "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" {
    m[r] = &result.consonants
  }
  for _, r := range text {
    ref, inMap := m[r]
    if inMap {
        *ref ++
    } else {
        result.other ++
    }
  }
  return result;
}

func main() {
  rt := analyseText("Hello, world!")
  fmt.Printf("%+v",rt)
}
```

---

edit: I extracted the analysing function, but the map rebuild per call makes multiple calls to the function inefficient. Some rewording (and typo fixing).

Comment: I like your use of structs in this case.

Comment: @Zygimantas ...but obviously not the use of map ;)